# Does each screen reader have a preferred browser? (i.e. JAWS, Voiceover, NVDA etc)

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I'm studying more on how to make my code more accessible but have recently stumbled upon Chase's accessibility statement making the comment that the JAWS screen reader tends to prefer Internet Explorer and NVDA works better with FireFox.

***Source:*** (https://www.chase.com/digital/resources/accessibility)

Since I do not have any of these installed on my computer, I'm curious first as to if each program actually does have a preference of which browser to use? And second, if they do have a preference - are there certain features of each program that don't work as well on other browsers?

**Question:** What are some of the things that I should be aware of when developing for these programs?

---

**EDIT:**
steveax shared a great source of information on this subject if you happened to be searching for an answer to this same question.

http://www.webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/#browsercombos

Comment: The best source of this information I've found: http://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/#browsercombos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

steveax shared a great source of information on this subject that definitely answers the question:

http://www.webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey6/#browsercombos